# What is the difference between facebook id and graph id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://graph.facebook.com/myusernamehere.11

```
{
"id": "5027xy014",
"first_name": "...",
"gender": "male",
"last_name": "...",
"locale": "en_US",
"name": "...",
"username": "myusernamehere.11"
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.1

```
{
"id": "101521xxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
"name": "xxxxxx yyyyy"
}
```

Why are these two id's different ? Which is is my real id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a "real" ID, the second one is an "App Scoped ID" - it is unique only for one specific App. See changelog for more information:

> App-scoped User IDs: To better protect people's information, when
>   people log into a version of your app that has been upgraded to use
>   Graph API v2.0, Facebook will now issue an app-scoped ID rather than
>   that person's orginal ID. However, for users that have previously
>   logged into your app, the user ID will not change.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: How do I get the "real" ID ? I checked the graph api and I don't see an option to get it.

Comment: you don´t get the real id, that´s the whole point of app scoped ids ;) - you can ONLY get it if you know the username, and you don´t get the username in api calls anymore either.

Comment: you don´t need the real id anyway, the app scoped id is unique in the app.